# How to display a Json message in a div inside a Html.BeginForm View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

Here is the code for my view and controller

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PdfHeaderAndFooterManager", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "formPdfImages" }))
 div id="resultMessage"></div>
```

}
CONTROLLER ACTION

```
public ActionResult PdfHeaderAndFooterManager(HttpPostedFileBase headerImage,   HttpPostedFileBase footerImage)
{

   //some code to declare variables


    if (headerImage != null)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(headerImage.ContentType))
        {
            headerImageContentType = imageHelper.IsValidImageType(headerImage.ContentType);

            if (headerImageContentType)
            {
                resizedHeaderImage = imageHelper.ResizeImage(headerImage.InputStream);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Please Upload an image* file less than 2GB." });
            }
        }
    }
    if (footerImage != null)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(footerImage.ContentType))
        {
            footerImageContentType = imageHelper.IsValidImageType(footerImage.ContentType);
            if (footerImageContentType)
            {   
                resizedFooterImage = imageHelper.ResizeImage(footerImage.InputStream);
            }
            else
            {

                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Please Upload an image* file less than 2GB." });
            }
        }
    }
    if (P24DataPrincipal.CurrentIdentity != null)
    {
        if (resizedHeaderImage != null || resizedFooterImage != null)
        {
          //add to DB code
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Image(s) Uploaded Successfully." });

        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new {success = false, message = "Upload atleast 1 image file." });

        }

    }

    return View("someview");

}
```

Can someone please assist me on how would have to write a jquery function to just display the Json results returned in the action above in my view. THANKS

Answer (score 2):

EDITORIAL NOTE

It would appear that you want to send back JSON OR an Image. You can probably do some interesting things with the HTML 5 Blob API (or sending the image back as a JSON payload with a DATA URI). In general, there is no simple solution to this, especially via AJAX.

END NOTE

Assuming jQuery 1.5 or better:

```
jQuery.post('/TheController/PdfHeaderAndFooterManager')
   .success(function(d){
        jQuery('#resultMessage').html(d.message).attr('data-action-success',d.success);
   }).error(function(){
      jQuery('#resultMessage').html('There was an error sending data to the server.').attr('data-action-success', false);
   });
```

And then you can do something fun in CSS like.:

```
[data-action-success=true]{
 color: green;
}
[data-action-success=false]{
 color: red;
}
```

It strikes me that you're returning different types of results. This is fairly uncommon and I would recommend that you split the "Show the form action (a GET action)" and the "Save a form (a POST action)". The GET could return an HTML action result. The POST could always return JSON.

Comment: I have them split already, I have a get and a post that does exactly what u saying, thanks for replying will tryout ur approach at work tomorrow and let u know how it goes, oh and by the way saving aretrieving the images is no problem, that works, i just want to display some confirmation/validation messages(JSON) in my view/page using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult PdfHeaderAndFooterManager(HttpPostedFileBase headerImage,   HttpPostedFileBase footerImage)
{

   //some code to declare variables

if (headerImage != null)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(headerImage.ContentType))
    {
        headerImageContentType = imageHelper.IsValidImageType(headerImage.ContentType);

        if (headerImageContentType)
        {
            resizedHeaderImage = imageHelper.ResizeImage(headerImage.InputStream);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ResultMessage="<span style='color:red'">Please Upload an image* file less than 2GB.</span>";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
if (footerImage != null)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(footerImage.ContentType))
    {
        footerImageContentType = imageHelper.IsValidImageType(footerImage.ContentType);
        if (footerImageContentType)
        {   
            resizedFooterImage = imageHelper.ResizeImage(footerImage.InputStream);
        }
        else
        {

            ViewBag.ResultMessage="<span style='color:red'">Please Upload an image* file less than 2GB.</span>";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
if (P24DataPrincipal.CurrentIdentity != null)
{
    if (resizedHeaderImage != null || resizedFooterImage != null)
    {
      //add to DB code
            ViewBag.ResultMessage="<span style='color:green'">Image(s) Uploaded Successfully.</span>";
            return View();
    }
    else
    {
            ViewBag.ResultMessage="<span style='color:red'">Upload atleast 1 image file.</span>";
            return View();
    }

}
```

}

And in **View**,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PdfHeaderAndFooterManager", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "formPdfImages" })){
 <div id="resultMessage">
    @ViewBag.ResultMessage
 </div>
}
```

Try this, hope it will help you.